# How to Change this JS to Use GetElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to make this JS add a class to another class (not an id):

```
 var d = document.getElementById("div1");
 d.className = d.className + " other class";
```

ie.

```
  var d = document.getElementsByClassName("div1");
  d.className = d.className + " other class";
```

I have a pen here that you can toy with: http://codepen.io/xkurohatox/pen/wMWKKM

Ideally it would be nice for something that functions with IE 8+ and modern browsers. JAVASCRIPT ONLY PLEASE (No JQuery please).

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You need to loop over the collection... Simple for loop. I am not sure how you are going to support IE8 with getElementsByClassName

Comment: Thanks @epascarello. I'm a beginner at JS so use GetElementsByClassName because that's all I was taught/could grasp.  Do you have any alternative suggestions?

Comment: getElementsByClassName is not supported in IE8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElements.className` actually returns a collection instead of a single value.

You need to access individual elements by using `array-bracket notation`.

```
var d = document.getElementsByClassName("gold")[0]'
```

The above gets the first element with the required class name.

Here's a demonstration

```js
var gold = document.getElementsByClassName("gold");

for (var i = 0; i < gold.length; i++) {
 gold[i].classList.add("bold");
}
```

```css
.gold { background: gold; }
.bold { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<p class="gold">Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>

<p class="gold">Paragraph 3</p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Richard Hamilton! I never would have considered using an array (well, maybe in a couple years...). Wonderful explanation, wish it were kept on the front page for others to view.

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector()` would be easier for the purpose of targeting a single element by a selector.

- Target element has an `id` ..... document.querySelector("#anyId");
- Target element has a `class` ... document.querySelector(".anyClass");
- Target element has no `class` or `id`, use the element's tag name ... document.querySelector("div");

If there's more than one target, then the first one will be selected.

Compatible with all browsers even IE8 (limited), see [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=queryselector) and for details see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors)

Btw, IE8 is no longer supported by MicroSoft, see this [obituary](http://zurb.com/article/1265/ie8-is-going-the-way-of-the-dodo-so-why-s)

```js
var target = document.querySelector('.AnyClass');

var button = document.querySelector('#AnyID');

button.onclick = function() {
  target.classList.add('newClass');
}
```

```css
.AnyClass {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.newClass {
  border: 3px dashed red;
  background: yellow;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
section {
  border: 1px dotted brown;
  background: blue;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="AnyClass">TARGET</div>
<button id="AnyID">addClass</button>
<section>SECTION</section>
```